# I am trying to run a script that will automatically download an xml format file from an internet website

Tags: xmlhttprequest

**Ok, so here is some information on what I am trying to do:**

Downloading the product feed
There are two ways to download your feed.

Clicking the XML or CSV icon to the right of the feed listing.
Programmatically downloading it using the feed access key
For many users, it's impractical to download the feed manually every day and then update your inventory by hand. For this reason, we've provided you with a way to download the feed programatically.

Programmatically downloading a feed

Write a script that can download files from the web. A developer or programmer should be able to help with this. See an example implementation.

Copy down your feed access key. The feed access key is a 32 character key that is unique to every feed.

Note: The feed access key should be kept a secret. The key can be found in the table above next to the feed name.

Decide on which format you prefer. Currently we have 2 available formats.

xml (opens in new window)
csv (opens in new window)
Direct your script to the url below (minus the brackets and substitute the variables with your own).

https://dropship.koleimports.com/download/{FEED ACCESS KEY}/{FORMAT}

**I have windows vista home basic for my operating system. I have no programmer experience at all, so very specific information would be much appreciated. I do know how to pull up the command prompt screen, but I want to make sure that any scripts I enter will do what needs to be done to get my product feed automatically updated daily. Please let me know if any further information would be needed to help me. Thank you to ANYONE who answers!**

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. Just change the first line.

```
var feed_access_key = "??????";
var format = "csv";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create object
var objXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

// Get the data
objXMLHTTP.open("GET", "https://dropship.koleimports.com/download/" + feed_access_key + "/" + format, false);
objXMLHTTP.send()

if (objXMLHTTP.Status == 200) {
    // Save to disk
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var path = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) + "\\download." + format;
    fso.DeleteFile(path);
    var f = fso.OpenTextFile(path, 2, true)
    f.Write(objXMLHTTP.responseText);
    f.Close();
    var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")  
    wsh.Run(path, 1, false);
}
```